# Trying to automate multi page google form submission. Help needed with entry sentinel

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, google-forms

I have a multi-page google form that I want to automatically fill using a python script. I have figured out how to do it including how to account for multi-pages. However, there is a particular element which needs you to click all checkboxes and I don't know how to handle that.

This is how the response header of this element looks like

```
entry.330812148_sentinel: 
entry.330812148: I agree to Term 1
entry.330812148: I agree to Term 2
entry.330812148: I agree to Term 3
entry.330812148: I agree to Term 4
```

You can get this once you Inspect the page under Network/formResponse/Form Data

This is my code (which does work except when you have this sentinel thing)

```
form_data = {'entry.1865579692':'Testing',
            'entry.562922459':'Test',
            'entry.330812148_sentinel':'',
            'entry.330812148':'I agree to Term 1',
            'entry.330812148':'I agree to Term 2',
            'entry.330812148':'I agree to Term 3',
            'entry.330812148':'I agree to Term 4',
            'pageHistory':'0,1,2'}
user_agent = {'Referer':'none','User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"}
try:
    r = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=user_agent)
```

This does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem today and removing the `_sentinel` did the trick for me.